# Error when switching scenes through a button node

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to switch scenes when you press a button, however, when I click it, nothing happens, and nothing gets printed. There are no errors, I am just wondering why it is not working. 
The node that I programmed DOES show up at the correct size and location, but when you tap on it nothing goes through. Thank you for any help.

Code:

```
class LevelScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var isFingerOnBlock = false
 let LevelOneName = "levelOne"

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        super.didMove(to: view)
        let Pineapple = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")
        Pineapple.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        Pineapple.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX - 200, y: self.frame.midY);
        Pineapple.name = "pineapple"
        addChild(Pineapple)

    }





   func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
    {
               let touch = touches.anyObject() as! UITouch
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let nodes = self.nodes(at: location)

        for node in nodes
        {
            if node.name == "pineapple"
            {
           print("ceeds")

                if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
                    // Configure the view.
                    let skView = self.view!
                    skView.showsFPS = true
                    skView.showsNodeCount = true

                    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
                    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

                    /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
                    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit

                    skView.presentScene(scene)


                }
                break
            }
        }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared

```
func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
```

There is no *built-in* function with that signature, and *you* never call that function; therefore your function is *never* called.

Comment: You may have intended to implement this function? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Matt! I fixed my code: It works now..

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,
                      with event: UIEvent?)    {
         let touch = touches.first!
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let node : SKNode = self.atPoint(location)
        if(atPoint(location) == node){
            if node.name == "levelOne" {
                if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
                    // Configure the view.
                    let skView = self.view as! SKView
                    skView.showsFPS = true
                    skView.showsNodeCount = true

                    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
                    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

                    /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
                    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit

                    skView.presentScene(scene)


                }
            }

        }

}
```